# Is there a simpler and easier way to calculate denomination in Java?

Tags: java

private int dollar1, cent50, cent10, cent5;

```
    private void calDenomination() {
    int myCoins = 1250;
    while(myCoins >= 100) {
        myCoins -= 100;
        dollar1 += 1;       
    }
    while(myCoins >= 50) {
        myCoins -= 50;
        cent50 += 1;        
    }
    while(myCoins >= 10) {
        myCoins -= 10;
        cent10 += 1;        
    }
    while(myCoins >= 5) {
        myCoins -= 5;
        cent5 += 1;     
    }
    
}
```

Is there a shorter way to do this? i am trying to write a program to check how many denomination coins are in the interger coin (cents).

The program should aim to give as much of the higher valued coin as possible and the total coins are always divisible by 5 (1250 % 5 = 0)

Comment: We can keep an array of coins denominations and iterate over it and keep a map to keep the denomination as a key and number of coins as value, then in each iteration can divide the value with denomination and put the value in map and reduce the value using remainder operators for next iteration, should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer division rounding with an array ( / and []) is the key to this one. Let coin[0] represent dollar, coin[1] be 50c etc. Then use coins[0] = myCoins/100 to determine the exact number of dollar and so on as listed below (note that these variables cannot be referenced outside their scope you can also remove all the System.out.printf() lines):

```
public class Example
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calDenomination(1250);
    }

private static void calDenomination(int myCoins) {
    System.out.printf("%d cents becomes...\n", myCoins);
    int[] coins;
    coins = new int [4];
    coins[0] = 1250/100;
    System.out.printf("%d : Dollar coins\n", coins[0]);
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[0] * 100;
    coins[1] = myCoins/50;
    System.out.printf("%d : 50c coins\n", coins[1]);
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[1] * 50;
    coins[2] = myCoins/10;
    System.out.printf("%d : 10c coins\n", coins[2]);
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[2] * 10;
    coins[3] = myCoins/5;
    System.out.printf("%d : 5c coins", coins[3]);
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[3] * 5;
}
}
```

OR

```
public class Example
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    calDenomination(1250);
}

private static void calDenomination(int myCoins) {
    int[] coins;
    coins = new int [4];
    coins[0] = 1250/100;
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[0] * 100;
    coins[1] = myCoins/50;
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[1] * 50;
    coins[2] = myCoins/10;
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[2] * 10;
    coins[3] = myCoins/5;
    myCoins = myCoins - coins[3] * 5;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems the results are not accurate with this one. If there are ten coins in myCoins, then the product should only have one, 10cent instead of one, 10cent, and one,5cent.

Comment: You're welcome Gingermint, I fixed the error so this maximizes the value of the coins. If you enter 1250 cents as the value in it splits to 12 dollar coins and 1 50c And if you entered 165 it would be exactly one of each. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Nice! just as I found the problem in your code, you came up with a fix. thank you so much! All the best to you Bryce.